# Unable to print a doc from specifice printer in Swing

Tags: java, swing

I am writing a code that should find list of printers on client machine and set a particulate printer for print a Doc. But I was goggling on net and I found code some think like that:

```
package org.ui;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import javax.print.*;
import javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet;
public class Printing {
    public static void main (String [] args) {       
        DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
        PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet ();       
        PrintService [] pservices = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices (flavor, aset);
        try {
            int printer = getPrinter(pservices);
            if(printer == -1) {
                throw new Exception("No network printer found");
            }
            DocPrintJob pj = pservices[0].createPrintJob();
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream ("c:///file.txt");
            Doc doc = new SimpleDoc (fis, flavor, null);
            pj.print (doc, aset);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace ();
        } 
    }
    private static int getPrinter(PrintService[] pservices) {
        int printer = -1;
        for(int i = 0; i<pservices.length; i++) {
            if(pservices[i].getName().contains("\\\\")) {
                System.out.println("network printer: " + pservices[i].toString());   
                printer = i;
                break;
            }        
        }
        return printer;
    }
}
```

But I am unable to get print on paper, can anyone tell me whats the problem in this code? Its a desktop application.

Comment: Do you get an exception? If yes, please update your post with it

Comment: You probably also meant `pservices[printer]` instead of `pservices[0]`

Comment: @Attila No, I am not getting any error but it does not printing any thing. And I am getting printer name at first position that means pservices[0] that's why i used pservices[0].

Comment: see if my second comment fixes it: you are searching for a specific printer, the index of which is returned in `printer`, but you are using the printer at index `0`

Comment: @Attila did as your second comment but still not working.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation of `print()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/print/DocPrintJob.html#print%28javax.print.Doc,%20javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet%29)

> [...] When the print method returns, printing may not yet have completed as printing may happen asynchronously, perhaps in a different thread. Application clients which want to monitor the success or failure should register a PrintJobListener.

This means that you need to register a `PrintJobListener` to be able to tell what the problem is:

Try:

```
pj.addPrintJobListener(new PrintJobListener() {
  @Override
  void printDataTransferCompleted(PrintJobEvent pje) {
    System.out.println("Transfer completed");
  }
  @Override
  void printJobCanceled(PrintJobEvent pje) {
    System.out.println("Cancelled");
  }
  @Override
  void printJobCompleted(PrintJobEvent pje) {
    System.out.println("Completed");
  }
  @Override
  void printJobFailed(PrintJobEvent pje) {
    System.out.println("Failed");
  }
  @Override
  void printJobNoMoreEvents(PrintJobEvent pje) {
    System.out.println("No more events");
  }
  @Override
  void printJobRequiresAttention(PrintJobEvent pje) {
    System.out.println("Check printer");
  }
});
```

before calling `print()` and see what gets outputed to the console

Comment: as per your answer I made changes in my code but now it shows on console : Transfer completed
No more events.
I am not getting meaning of it.

Comment: That means that the transfer of the document was completed (sent to printer, no problem), but the printer did not reply back with the print job itself being completed before closing the communication. Not sure what the cause of that might be. Is the printer showing anything?

Comment: is there any issue regarding default printer and specified printer. because i have two printers on my machine and default is HP-Lesser and I am trying to set another printer to do print.

Comment: @Balasaheb - you could try: send the document to all printers in `pservices`, see if it gets printed where you want it and find which one that is.  Also, if the HP is off and you try to print to that you should not see "Transfer completed".  If these don't help, I'm affraid I'm out of ideas.  Just to double check: can you print to the HP one using your program?